# NextJS How to add component level css based on conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app, I have a component where I want to add conditional styling.

So I have made a component-level stylesheet `MyComponent.module.css`, which has:

```
.primary {
  color: blue;
}

.secondary {
  color: orange
}
```

Then, in my component, I tried to do this:

```
import styles from "./MyComponent.module.css"

export default function MyComponent({ text, type }) {

  return (
    <button className={`${type === "primary" ? styles.primary : styles.secondary}`}>
      {text}
    </button>
  )
```

}

but this doesn't work e.g. returns `undefined`

So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the backticks.

```
import styles from "./style.module.css";
const App = () => {
    const type = "primary";
    const text = "Hello"
    return (
        <div className={type === "primary" ? styles.primary : styles.secondary}>
            {text}
        </div>
    );
};
export default App;
```